# Debug Hardhat with Foundry

Tags: hardhat, contract-debugging, foundry, framework

Can you debug a Hardhat project using Foundry?

I know that doing Foundry tests on Hardhat is possible through their plugin, but is it possible to debug also?

Comment: Not sure about Foundry. But I just released a new Solidity debugger extension for VS Code that allows you to debug Solidity projects with Hardhat. It is based on the unmaintained Meadow project.
Give it a try! https://soliditydebugger.org/

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go. Although still curious to know the answer of my post :)